# Can I change handler callbackfunction in another server handler

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to change the callback function within another server handler. I get a response "Cannot find function setCallbackFunction in object Generic." as a result of 
      app.getElementById('treeHandler').setCallbackFunction('noSelection');
while the handler is defined in the mainline as
     var handler = app.createServerHandler('nameSelected').setId('treeHandler');
so it looks as though we can't get elements of type ServerHandler within a server handler.

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct; you cannot get them back and do anything with them.

Comment: Thanks Corey, A little table of where the gets and sets work/don't work would help.

Comment: Any widget should be retrievable. Offhand I can't think of anything other than handlers that isn't.

Answer (score 0):

That is not completely correct, you can add an hidden element to application. Just adopt the axmaple below by using createHidden instead of createTextBox.

```
function doGet() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   var textBox1 = app.createTextBox().setName("textBox1");
   var textBox2 = app.createTextBox().setId("textBox2");
   app.add(textBox1);
   app.add(textBox2);
   var textBox3 = app.createTextBox().setName("textBox3");
   var panel = app.createFlowPanel();
   panel.add(textBox3);
   app.add(panel);
   var button = app.createButton("a button");
   var handler = app.createServerHandler("handlerFunction");
   handler.addCallbackElement(textBox1)
       .addCallbackElement(textBox2)
       .addCallbackElement(panel)
   button.addClickHandler(handler);
   app.add(button);
   return app;
 }

 function handlerFunction(eventInfo) {
   var parameter = eventInfo.parameter;
   // There's a lot of information in 'parameter' about the event too, but we'll focus here
   // only on the callback elements.
   var textBox1 = parameter.textBox1;  // the value of textBox1
   var textBox2 = parameter.textBox2;  // undefined! setId is not the same as setName
   var textBox3 = parameter.textBox3;  // works! the parent "panel" was a callback element
 }
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_serverhandler#addCallbackElement